# Python - Opening multiple SSH within (inside) eachother

Tags: python, ssh

Here is what I want to do :

1. SSH to server 1
2. inside server 1, SSH to server 2
3. inside server 2, SSH to server 3
4. inside server 3, run a single command ( like mysql )
5. inside mysql console, run another command.
6. then exit all the way to server 1

Is it possible to do a procedure like this ? If yes, then how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *possible*: Just execute `ssh` (or a corresponding Python program you upload first) on each new hop, and when you finally reach the target, execute `mysql`.

However, it's not *advisable*: You should never enter passwords (or worse, store private keys) for one server on another server. That means that if server 1 is ever compromised, your whole network is compromised.

Instead, use the first two ssh sessions to create tunnels to the next hop, either with the `-L` option of the command-line `ssh` (which you probably need to use anyways, see above), or with [paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323471/problem-originating-ssh-tunnels-from-python).

Comment: Sorry to reply late! I caught a cold. Anyway thanks! But I am a beginner in python. I just wrote a program which could read/write to text file. nothing more. Can you please point to a specific page what function/module do i have to use. I know there are many many ways to do ssh in python. If it is possible give me an example of 2 ssh being within eachother!